# Ignore Properties in OnModelCreating

Tags: entity-framework-5, fluent-interface, navigation-properties

I'm attempting to use Bounded (Db) Contexts in Entity Framework 5.0, and I'm having problems excluding a property from one of the classes included in a specific context.  Here is the information (I'll shorten for brevity)

BaseContext.cs

```
public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    static BaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected BaseContext()
        : base("name=Development")
    {

    }
}
```

IContext.cs

```
public interface IContext : IDisposable
{
    int SaveChanges();
    void SetModified(object entity);
    void SetAdded(object entity);
}
```

ISuiteContext.cs

```
public interface ISuiteContext : IContext
{
    IDbSet<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

SuiteContext.cs

```
public class SuiteContext : BaseContext<SuiteContext>, ISuiteContext
{
    public IDbSet<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }
    ...
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrganizationsConfiguration());
        ...
        ...

        modelBuilder.Ignore<Colors>();
    }
}
```

Organizations.cs:

```
public class Organizations
{
    public Organizations()
    {
        Colors = new List<Colors>();
        ...
        ...
    }

    public int Organization_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address_1 { get; set; }
    public string Address_2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Colors> Colors { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

OrganizationConfiguration.cs:

```
public class OrganizationsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Organizations>
{
    public OrganizationsConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Organizations");

        HasKey(o => o.Organization_ID);

        ...
        ...
        HasMany(o => o.Colors);
    }
}
```

How I'm Using (Web API Test Proj)

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IOrganizationRepository _orgRepo;

    public ValuesController()
    {
        _uow = new UnitOfWork<SuiteContext>(new SuiteContext());
        _orgRepo = new OrganizationRepository(_uow);
    }

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<Organizations> Get()
    {
        return _orgRepo.RetrieveAll().AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And the exception that is occurring:

> The navigation property 'Colors' is not a declared property type on
>   type            'Organizations'.  Verify that it has not been excluded
>   from the model and that it is a valid navigation property

All I want is for the 'SuiteContext' to have access to Organizations, but not the children (Colors, and a few others)

What am I missing?  Perhaps I'm interpreting the exception incorrectly?

---

***Update #1***

I've tried (without success - same exception):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Organizations>().Ignore(o =>o.Colors);

modelBuilder.Ignore<Colors>();
```

***Update #2***

I appears it has something to do with the `OrganizationsConfiguration.cs` class and the `HasMany()` methods.
If I take out the `HasMany(o => o.Colors)`, then I am able to Ignore the classes/properties the way I intend.  However, this also causes the database creation to FAIL on recreation.  Damned if I do, damned if I don't!

Comment: Removed the DDD tags since that isn't really DDD. http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: I'm in the same boat right now. I've reverse generated a sizable DB (800+ tables) into a single context that I'd like to keep for migrations, etc.

Then I'd like to have BoundContexts that map more closely to domain logic. All of the foreign keys are killing me due to navigational properties.

I'm being forced to: 1. alter the mapping, or worse duplicate the mapping in my bound context.

Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're ignoring the class but you also need to ignore the property.

```
Ignore(o => o.Colors);
```

I've ignored scalar properties in apps before (and did that in the video you saw :) )  but not navigation properties, so I just tested to ensure that the model builder is happy with it. And it is. But you should just do a few integration tests to make sure it all works as expected in your app.

Comment: I tried utilizing both instances of Ignore (combined, and either), but it throws the same exception every time.

Comment: if you have code that references the property in the model builder (other than ignore) then that will take precedence. If you don't want the property to be mapped then ignore it and remove any other code for it (re hasmany). But it seems that *something* is still trying to add Colors into the db. is update2 giving you the same error or a different one. What's the failure? Do you want to send me your domain classes and dbcontext/config classes and I can see what's happening?

Comment: If I comment out the `HasMany()` methods in Configuration, then everything works.  However, if I try to drop and recreate the database with those `HasMany()` methods commented out, the database creation fails.  Thanks for the offer, but I'd REALLY love to figure this out :)  Besides, you're busy :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post and you probably have figured this out, though this may help someone else.  The `Ignore` works well in a 1-1 scenario.  The 1-Many is the issue.

In your example above, you would need to do the following:

```
 modelBuilder.Ignore<ICollection<Color>>();
```

Comment: OMG, that makes complete sense, and no, I haven't figured it out - kind of forgot about it actually.  I'll try this and get back you, but for now, you at least get an upvote :)