# Entity Framework Context Picking up more entities than mapped in the context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When using a Context class with only a couple references to entities, Entity Framework seems to be pulling in a bunch of other entity references for its nefarious uses, and this is causing problems for me.  (I'm getting the error like "entity such and such can't use the same table as entity so and so because they're not in the same type hierarchy or whatever".)   My question is **not** about this specific error, but why Entity Framework is pulling in entities outside of my context at all.

I have an Entity Framework DbContext sub-class with only a couple references like the following:

```
public class FruitContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Apple> Apples { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Orange> Oranges { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Linqpad to query this context, and when I expand the FruitContext node, it shows me that it contains "Apples" and "Oranges" as expected, but then it also shows me "Beans" and "Asparagi" which aren't in the FruitContext at all, and aren't in the type hierarchies of either Apple or Orange.  Why is EF pulling in these entities?  Now it MAY be the case that I'm referring to these Beans and Asparagi entities in a repository or something, but would EF care about that?  Is there a way to tell EF for a particular context that it should only care about what's actually in the context and exclude any entities that it's grabbing from wherever else?

**Edit 1**: Here's the Orange class:

```
[Table("FOOD")]
public class Orange
{
  public Int32 Juiciness { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Asparagus class which is being pulled in for whatever reason, but why?  It shares the same table as Orange, but why should EF care since it's outside the context and not nested in the same type hierarchy as Orange?

```
[Table("FOOD")]
public class Asparagus
{
  public String SomeVegetableField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the classes Apple and Orange?

Comment: It might be impossible to locate the error without a more complete code sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Have you added a connection to the LinqPad session? Perhaps LinqPad's pulling from that and not from your context.

Comment: OK crap - as it turns out, Orange does have Asparagus deep within its citrusy class hierarchy...  Can I somehow treat the offending member as "NotMapped" dynamically when the FruitContext is newed up?

Comment: I found this post that shows how to ignore something at run-time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917006/ignore-properties-in-onmodelcreating.  This fixes my problem and allows me to ignore Asparagi and Beans.